# syntax highlighting gtksourceview, use another xml file?

Tags: xml, syntax-highlighting, gedit, gtksourceview

We can add our language definition in `gedit` in a `XML file`format, in the `/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/` folder,
But can we in our `XML` refere to an other `XML` file?
In my language definition i want to add some script (`C , Python , Java`...) when they are between some special character, since they already have a XML file that i juste want to use it.

Anyone have a clue on achieving this?

https://developer.gnome.org/gtksourceview/stable/lang-tutorial.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's done here, for example, by namespacing the name of the context that you want to refer to with the language name: https://github.com/GNOME/gtksourceview/blob/0fdbdfb7d669f2726a9de548fcdeffcd68f5c0a1/data/language-specs/m4.lang#L998

This includes the syntax definitions for shell code into some contexts in M4/Autoconf highlighting.